# chmod cannot access to 'uploads/' :file or folder doesn't exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian

i did this

sudo chmod -R 775 uploads/

and got this

chmod cannot access to 'uploads/' :file or folder doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Your command is syntactically correct. The reason why it is reporting `file or folder doesn't exist` will be that the file or folder doesn't exist.

As you are using a relative path, you may wish to ensure that the current directory when you type the command is the parent directory of where you expect the `uploads` directory to reside. Note in particular that `sudo` will run the `chmod` command from the existing current directory (for example, it would not change to the home directory of the root user merely because it is running the command as root).

If you wish to check whether `uploads` is a valid path relative to the current directory, then use the `ls` command (without command-line arguments) to list the contents of the current directory, and see whether `uploads` (case-sensitive) is mentioned in the output.